# How to know Gigaspace is connected in Java application at startup

Tags: java, gigaspaces

I am using spring Application and my gigaspace is connecting at startup. I am not getting any exception, if gigaspace is down.

```
@Override
     public void onContextRefreshed(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
         String gigaSpaceURL = null;
         LOGGER.info("({}) initializing gigaspaces client", getName());
         try {
             initGSProxy();
             Iterator<Map.Entry<ConfiguredSpace, Space>> entries = spaces.entrySet().iterator();
             while (entries.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry<ConfiguredSpace, Space> entry = entries.next();
                 LOGGER.info("({}) initialing space- key=" +
entry.getKey() + ", value = " + entry.getValue(),
                         getName());
                 // TODO : Need to verify Boolean Value Input
                 gigaspace.createSpace(entry.getKey().name(),
entry.getValue().getURL(), false);
                 gigaSpaceURL = entry.getValue().getURL();
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return;

         }

   GenericUtil.updateLogLevel("INFO",
"com.renovite.ripps.ap.gs.Spaces");
LOGGER.info("\n************************************\nConnected with Gigaspace successfully:URL:" + gigaSpaceURL
                 + "\n************************************\n");
         GenericUtil.updateLogLevel("ERROR",
"com.renovite.ripps.ap.gs.Spaces");

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take reference of Gigaspace by using getGigaSpace() method which takes spacekey as an argument.If it throw exception at run time, it means application is not able to connect with specified Gigaspace url.

Or more elegant way, In your Gigaspace proxy class (which actually implements IGigaspace) override the getGigaSpace() method such that it will return null if connection is not possible.

/** The spaces. */
    private transient Map spaces = new HashMap<>();

@Override
    public GigaSpace getGigaSpace(String spaceKey) {

```
    if(spaces.get(spaceKey) != null){
        return spaces.get(spaceKey).getGigaSpace();
    }
  return null;
}
```

spaces is a Map of all urls that are registered with Gigapsace.If no one is registered, we are returning null in the above method.